# How to resize web page with CSS code on any screen size without auto scaling?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a website designed using ReactJS. The interface when compiled on Google Chrome with my screen size is 1920x1080, but when accessing with a screen size with a smaller resolution it automatically scales compared to the original interface.

I want to freeze my website when compiling on any screen size.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute width and height?

Comment: What do you mean with `freeze` . Have you heard of responsive webdesign?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Websites that aren't responsive don't get favored by search engines.  Why do you want it to be static?